# How can I change my code to output to the console and to an output log in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

This is the first thing I've written in Powershell (I'm more of a VBA guy) so excuse if there are many problems you may find with it. I'm really just winging it so any help is much appreciated.

I've made this for my work to basically grab the main sub-folders and spit out their size, file count and folder count. It works great and the output log comes out how I want it to. I would like it to update in the console as well as the output log as we quite often are checking large folders so it can take some time so I would like to let the person see it update as it does each folder. However, I cannot figure it out.

I saw maybe `Tee-Object` can/should be used but I don't quite know how to incorporate it with all the lines I want to output. Each line I want to be output is with the `echo` command. Write-Host seemed to only work if I disabled the log.

Here is my code:

```
While ($true){
    $startDirectory = Read-Host "Enter path/directory"
    if (Test-Path -Path $startDirectory) { break }
    Write-Host "Wrong path. Please try again" -ForegroundColor Red
}
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Getting information..." -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host "This can take a while if the selected directory is large and/or contains a lot of files. An output log will be created at the end."
Write-Host ""
 
$directoryItems = Get-ChildItem $startDirectory | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true} | Sort-Object
$ParentFileSize = 0
$TotalFiles = 0
$TotalFolders = 0
$SubFileCount = 0
$SubFolderCount = 0
$SubFileSize = 0
$TotalSize = 0
$Tab = [char]9 

$(
echo "Output file generated to: $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Output.txt" " "
echo "List of Folders in '$startDirectory'" " "
echo "Size (GB): $Tab Files: $Tab Folders: $Tab Folder Name:" " "

$ParentFileCount = (Get-ChildItem $startDirectory -File).Count
$ParentFolderCount = (Get-ChildItem $startDirectory -Directory).Count
$ParentFileSize = Get-ChildItem $startDirectory -File | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
$ParentFileSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($ParentFileSize.sum / 1GB)
foreach ($i in $directoryItems)
{
    $subFolderItems = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -recurse -force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | Measure-Object -property Length -sum | Select-Object Sum
    $FolderSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($subFolderItems.sum / 1GB)
    $FileCount = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse -File | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}
    $FolderCount = Get-ChildItem $i.FullName -Recurse -Directory | Measure-Object | %{$_.Count}

    echo "$FolderSize $Tab $Tab $FileCount $Tab $Tab $FolderCount $Tab $Tab $i"
    $SubFileCount = $SubFileCount + $FileCount
    $SubFolderCount = $SubFolderCount + $FolderCount
    $SubFileSize = $SubFileSize + $FolderSize
}

$TotalFolders = $SubFolderCount + $ParentFolderCount
$TotalFiles = $SubFileCount + $ParentFileCount
$TotalSize = $SubFileSize +  $ParentFileSize
$TotalSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($TotalSize)
$SubFileSize = "{0:N2}" -f ($SubFileSize)

echo " " " " "Total in '$startdirectory':" " "
echo "Size: $TotalSize GB ($SubFileSize GB in sub-folders)" "Files: $TotalFiles ($SubFileCount in sub-folders)" "Folders: $TotalFolders ($SubFolderCount in sub-folders)"

) *>&1 > $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Output.txt

Invoke-Item $env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\Output.txt
```

Comment: The reason `Write-Host` doesn't write to console is because in Windows PowerShell v5+ it uses the information stream. This means `*>&1` redirects `write-host` to success stream which is redirected to your file. If you only want to capture success and errors, then `2>&1` for example will do so while showing `write-host` output at the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tee-Object` is the right way to go. It allows you to simultaneously write to a file and forward the input down the pipe, where it finally ends up in the console.

Move the code who's output you want to feed to `Tee-Object` into a function or script block.

Example using a scriptblock:

```
& {
    Write-Output 'foo'
    Sleep 2
    Write-Output 'bar'
} *>&1 | Tee-Object log.txt
```

Example using a function:

```
Function FooBar {
    Write-Output 'foo'
    Sleep 2
    Write-Output 'bar'
}

FooBar *>&1 | Tee-Object log.txt
```

The `Sleep` in my examples is just there to demonstrate that the output is shown while the script block or function is still running.

If you'd change the scriptblock to `$( some code )` you would only receive the output at once, when the code has finished.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I think I've figured it all out and got it to work now.

Answer (score 0):

```
"some text" | Tee-Object -Variable consoleOutput | Out-File "d:\logFileName.log"
Write-Host $consoleOutput
```

Comment: Hi I appreciate the response but I'm not sure you fully understood what I'm asking? This doesn't work for me and there are many things missing which I have in my original code. Mainly, The user needs to input the directory to search (which should test if it exists and if not get the user to retry), then it should list only the first sub-folders in that directory and not every sub-folder within those sub-folders (to 2 decimal places in the Size), and then the log should output to the desktop. I like the template way you use but it just doesn't work for me at this point.

Comment: Again, really my only issue I am facing with my code is that I want it to show the folder list in the console as the script runs as well as outputting to the log file. At the moment it just logs and doesn't show anything in the console.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.